# Best practice for URLs in Java template engines

Tags: java, template-engine

I used a couple of Java template engine (Mustache, Freemarker) and I always struggle on how to deal with the same problem.

Assume you have a template with a piece of code like:

```
<a href="/{{article.name}}/{{article.color}}/home.html">
```

where `article` is an object passed from a controller to the template engine, for instance. 
Then, I always see the same problems. I have to hardcode the url in several pages, if I change it then I have to look at it manually everywhere. E.g., if I want to change the URI like this:

```
<a href="article/{{article.name}}/{{article.color}}">
```

Then I have to change it everywhere.

Yeah, maybe I can define each url in something that is enabled by specific template engines (e.g. includes), but I'm wondering if there is a best practice.
One possible solution I was thinking about is to create the urls on the server side (e.g. in the controller) and sending them to the view.

Which are the best approaches from the point of view of re-usability, correctness and flexibility?

Answer (score 0):

You said it: The best (most flexible and maintenable) practice is to produce the URLs in the controller and send them to the view: That is called [HATEOAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS).

Comment: I think the question is about server-side template engines and if the controller should generate the URLs used by (server-side) views. HATEOAS it is about sending URLs to the _client_ in REST webservices, so it's not really relevant here.